# MVC 5 Register area registeration and fully trust

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, deployment, web-deployment

After I deployed my site [this screen displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCNPr.jpg) with the following message and I selected to fully trust but the site is still not working.

Any suggestions or help?

Attempt by security transparent method 'MyWebInterface.MvcApplication.Application_Start()' to access security critical method 'System.Web.Mvc.AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()' failed.

Assembly 'xxxx, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is partially trusted, which causes the CLR to make it entirely security transparent regardless of any transparency annotations in the assembly itself.  In order to access security critical code, this assembly must be fully trusted

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar problem once and resolved it with the code below in 
*assemblyinfo.cs*

```
[assembly: SecurityRules(SecurityRuleSet.Level1)]
```

.